# CreateFile() ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION with single thread

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

Why can't a single thread open the same file tqize using `CreateFile` and an *exclusive file lock* to the process? The example below will fail on the second attempt to open the file by the same thread with a `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` exception:

> **ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION** 32 (0x20) The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another **process**.

Emphasis on the word "process" above; it is the same process (and even the same thread) that tries to open the same file twize.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hOutputFile1 = CreateFile(
        // File name
        L"test.dat",
        // Requested access to the file 
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        // Share mode. 0 equals exclusive lock for the process
        0,
        // Pointer to a security attribute structure
        NULL,
        // Action to take on file
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        // File attributes and flags
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        // Template file
        NULL
        );
    if (hOutputFile1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // Error
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        return (int)lastError;
    }

    // opening the same file for the second time will return a ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION exception
    HANDLE hOutputFile2 = CreateFile(
        // File name
        L"test.dat",
        // Requested access to the file 
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        // Share mode. 0 equals exclusive lock by the process
        0,
        // Pointer to a security attribute structure
        NULL,
        // Action to take on file
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        // File attributes and flags
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        // Template file
        NULL
        );
    if (hOutputFile2 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // Error
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        return (int)lastError;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message text is a bit misleading, but the fact that the two calls to `CreateFile` are made from the same thread in the same process doesn't change anything. Once the first call to `CreateFile` has been made, then subsequent calls to `CreateFile`, irrespective of where they originate, must obey the sharing rules.

I guess the error message text tries to capture the most common source of a sharing violation. Namely two processes competing for the same file. But the simple fact is that once you have opened a file with exclusive sharing, then no other attempts to open the file can succeed.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't asking for a change. I really don't mind. I just feel that better answers (not that mine here is at all special) deserve reward and that speed never beats quality. Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 1):

That old message is misleading. It doesn't matter what process or thread is opening a file. File sharing is handle-based.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx):

> dwShareMode [in]:
>
> If this parameter is zero and CreateFile succeeds, the file or device
>   cannot be shared and cannot be opened again until the handle to the
>   file or device is closed.

This is just talking about `opening` the file or device and the error message is something general and confusing.

Instead of trying to re-open the file, you should hold the handle and do your job.

Comment: This isn't always possible, for example, the case of a existing API which abstracts away platform-specific file descriptors or handle. It's not **always** practical to have access to the raw `HANDLE`, although in practice it generally should be preferred. Shared reading/writing solves this nicely, in that case.